# I'm trying to calculate a timelapse in SQL but it gives me the result in 'microseconds'

Tags: sql, time, data-analysis

I'm working in a project and in order to know how much time happened between two dates i'm using the following code:

`select (DATE_COMPLETED - DATE_STARTED) as avg_days`

The problem is that when I run the code it shows the new column but the format answer is for example:

{"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 2803077000000}

As you may infer I want that information in days, not in 'microseconds'

By the way, the format of the Date data I'm using is '2021-02-24T02:33:00.000+0000'.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: The type of the columns is timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you get microseconds and you want days, use arithmetic:

```
select (DATE_COMPLETED - DATE_STARTED) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000) as avg_days
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work :( now it went from being: {"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 2803077000000} to be {"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 5599}. But thanks for helping :)